App crashes when trying to open bottom sheet when app is in background
I have an app that has a timer, when timer stops there should be shown a bottomsheet with results, but when the app is in background I got this crash:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment HealthExamResultBottomSheetFragment{52bc1d1} (b00dde02-255d-4ab4-b759-0d3f8056d273) not associated with a fragment manager.
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getParentFragmentManager(Fragment.java:1112)
    at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.dismissInternal(DialogFragment.java:612)
    at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.dismissAllowingStateLoss(DialogFragment.java:574)
    at com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment.dismissAllowingStateLoss(BottomSheetDialogFragment.java:63)
    at co.tenton.admin.autoshkolla.architecture.fragments.health.HealthExamFragment.showHealthResults(HealthExamFragment.kt:214)
    at co.tenton.admin.autoshkolla.architecture.fragments.health.HealthExamFragment.openExamResults(HealthExamFragment.kt:200)
    at co.tenton.admin.autoshkolla.architecture.fragments.health.HealthExamFragment.access$openExamResults(HealthExamFragment.kt:37)
    at co.tenton.admin.autoshkolla.architecture.fragments.health.HealthExamFragment$finishExamDialog$dialog$1.invoke(HealthExamFragment.kt:185)

I guess the problem is that i am calling the dismissAllowingStateLoss():
private fun showHealthResults(item: Exam) {
    val fm = activity?.supportFragmentManager ?: return

    healthExamResultBottomSheetFragment?.dismissAllowingStateLoss()
    healthExamResultBottomSheetFragment = HealthExamResultBottomSheetFragment(item)
    val bottomSheet = healthExamResultBottomSheetFragment ?: return
    bottomSheet.isCancelable = false
    if (!bottomSheet.isAdded) {
        if (!fm.isStateSaved) {
            bottomSheet.show(fm, "HealthExamResultBottomSheet")
        } else {
            fm.registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(object : FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks() {
                override fun onFragmentResumed(fm: FragmentManager, f: Fragment) {
                    super.onFragmentResumed(fm, f)
                    if (f == this@HealthExamFragment) {
                        fm.unregisterFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(this)
                        showHealthResults(item)
                    }
                }
            }, false)
        }
    }
}


I'd assume, that you'd have to bring the app back into the foreground first, while in the second linked answer, the one with lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed also might be applicable.

I don't understand how the answer with lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed might be applicable, can you explain to me?

Maybe I wasn't clear in my question, if the app is closed and the timer ends the bottom sheet will not show, if i click a button to show it, it will show this crash above.

As stated, primarily you have to bring the app into the foreground again, then it shouldn't crash anymore. And I also can't tell without trying how option 2 could be applied, this was just the same error message. I've just added both answers, because the second one may eventually also be relevant. I'd suggest to simply look up that method in the documentation.

I mean, you could as well use an Intent, which tells the Activity to show the BottomSheet.
